# iOS Custom control - weird looking text

Tags: ios, text, drawrect

I have implemented custom control (chart) based on `UIView`. Overriding `drawRect`. 
Now trying to put labels using this line:

```
[[[barLabels objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"day"] drawInRect:someRect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

But as you can see on the picture:

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/15ppvg2.png]

The text is displayed in a very strange way. Any ideas why?
P.S. Full sources of drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(ctx, true);

    for(int i = 0; i < [barRects count]; i++)
    {
        CGRect someRect = [[barRects objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];

        [self drawBar:someRect context:ctx];


        [[barValues objectAtIndex:i] drawInRect:CGRectMake(someRect.origin.x + 0.5f, someRect.origin.y + someRect.size.height - margin - hAxisValuesMargin + 0.5f, someRect.size.width, someRect.size.height) withFont:[AppController brandFontLight:8] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

        [[[barLabels objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"day"] drawInRect:someRect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

     [[[barLabels objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"month"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(someRect.origin.x, someRect.origin.y + hAxisFontSize, someRect.size.width, someRect.size.height) withFont:[AppController brandFontBold:10] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    }


    UIGraphicsPopContext();

}
```

Comment: My guess: You're adding and adding and adding again (a loop?) the labels. I guess that if you count all the view inside your view, before and after, you may have surprise. That's, or you added some quite code in `drawRect`, which is hard to debug if we don't see it.

Comment: If Larme's recommendation can not solve. Let's try +0.5pixel to x or y position

Comment: Added full source code. +0.5 pixel does not work;(  I also checked and the code for each label is executed only once.

Comment: I found the root cause! The drawBar() method had an orphan CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2);  call! Now it works, thanks all!